# How Does Prototype Chain Works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to establish a prototype chain for the Thief class to inherit the methods of Assassin class and it works as below:

```
function Assassin() {
       this.sonicBlow = function() {return "Performs Sonic Blow!"};
       this.enchantDeadlyPoison = function() {return "Performs Enchant Deadly Poison!"}
   }

   Assassin.prototype.venomDust = function () {return "Performs Venom Dust!"}

   function Thief() {
       this.hide = function() {return "Performs Hide!"}
   }

   Thief.prototype = new Assassin()

   let thief = new Thief()

   let sin1 = new Assassin()

   console.log(thief.sonicBlow())

   console.log(thief.enchantDeadlyPoison())

   console.log(thief.venomDust())
```

but when I try to get the Assassin class to inherit the Thief class method, it does not work if i do this:

```
   Assassin.prototype = new Thief()

   console.log(sin1.hide())
```

It says: **sin1.hide is not a function**

Can anybody tell me why please?

Comment: sin1.__proto__ =  thief.__proto__

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be more clear about what you are trying to do. Keep in mind that prototype chaining is supposed to be a chain without loops. You need to decide whether Assassin should inherit from Thief or vice versa. If you want both Thief and Assassin to have a common hide method, for example, you may want to create a third class, BadGuy, and have both Assassin and Thief inherit from that.

Finally, ECMAScript 6 (i.e. Javascript 6) has better support for classes and inheritance. You may want to check this out: http://es6-features.org/#ClassInheritance

Answer (score 0):

**The reference between an object and the function's prototype is established at the time of the object instantiation.**

so when you come to this line of code:

```
  let sin1 = new Assassin()
```

sin1 instance [[prototype]] object has ONLY `venomDust()`. but when you come to this line of the code:

```
  Assassin.prototype = new Thief()
```

you are changing the prototype of the Assassin. So only new instances after this line of code will have access to the `Thief.prototype` object.

since `sin1` is created with the old prototype of Assassin(), `sin1` will only have access to the old prototype of Assassin(). even though you changed the prototype, old prototype will still be live because `sin1` is referencing. If there was no instance of Assassin() that was referencing to the old prototype, it would be garbage collected.